# how can i fix it for telegram ? peer channel

Tags: python, object, attributes, telegram, telegram-bot

I need help with this code. 
A month ago, I modified it to fit with me.
since three days, I suffer from an error that I could not fix .. He used to work before and now no
Thank you so much.

This is the source of the project
I have just modified the previous mistakes
I'm a beginner with only a month and a half experience

https://github.com/P-Alban/Telegram-collector

```
import sys
from getpass import getpass
from time import sleep

from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.errors import UsernameNotOccupiedError
from telethon.errors import FloodWaitError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch, InputChannel

# First you need create app on https://my.telegram.org
api_id = api_id
api_hash = 'api_hash'
phone = '+....Phone'
limit = 100

def get_chat_info(username, client):
    try:
        chat = client(ResolveUsernameRequest(username))
    except UsernameNotOccupiedError:
        print('Chat/channel not found!')
        sys.exit()
    result = {
        'chat_id': chat.peer.channel_id,
        'access_hash': chat.chats[0].access_hash
    }
    return result


def dump_users(chat, client):
    counter = 0
    offset = 0
    chat_object = InputChannel(chat['chat_id'], chat['access_hash'])
    all_participants = []
    print('Process...')
    while True:
        participants = client.invoke(GetParticipantsRequest(
                    chat_object, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit
                ))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        all_participants.extend(['{} {}'.format(x.id, x.username)
                           for x in participants.users])
        users_count = len(participants.users)
        offset += users_count
        counter += users_count
        print('{} users collected'.format(counter))
        sleep(2)
    with open('users.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(map(str, all_participants)))


def main():
    channel_name = input('Input a channel name, without "@": ')
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

    print('Connecting...')

    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        try:
            client.send_code_request(phone)
            print('Sending a code...')
            client.sign_in(phone, code=input('Enter code: '))
            print('Successfully!')
        except FloodWaitError as FloodError:
            print('Flood wait: {}.'.format(FloodError))
            sys.exit()
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            client.sign_in(password=getpass('Enter password: '))
            print('Successfully!')
    dump_users(get_chat_info(channel_name, client), client)
    print('Done!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Generally, it is good practice to post the code snipped and the specific error that you are receiving.  That will help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your interest .. I hope so This is the error message I'm having an attribute error and runtime I have been unable to solve for almost 4 days and I am searching

see this pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGwtc.png